# Testing UVA and UVB protection in sunglasses?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, vision

Is there an inexpensive way to test UVA and UVB protection in sunglasses?

(Or does all plastic block a majority of UVA and UVB light?)

*[This question](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/12640/) was posed by another StackExchange user in the Health SE site, and the mods recommended posting it here, as physicists would likely be the only people to know the answer.*

Comment: Y'know how the colors fade from newspaper/magazine photos when you expose them to sunlight for a few weeks?  That's a photo-chemical reaction, triggered by light---espeially by blue-to-ultraviolet light.  If you could identify some visible chemical reaction that only occurs in the presence of light in some interesting range of wavelengths, that could be the basis of your cheap test.  Otherwise, you're going to need an ultraviolet spectrophotometer or something like.  I don't know what they cost, but probably goes beyond "inexpensive."

Comment: you can purchase ultraviolet dosimetry paper in the form of stickers that you can stick to the surface of your choice. they change color in accordance with cumulative UV dosage but I do not know if they allow discrimination between short and long wavelength UV. However, they are not expensive.